# Syntax error point >>> . <<< - Shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to open a list of files, whose names are stored and called in a column of a .csv file.

Here is the header and 1st line of my metadata.csv file:

```
Sample_name,file1,file2,i7_Index_Name,i7_Sequence,i5_Index_Name,i5_Sequence,Well,Set,PrimerF,PrimerR,Locus
18S-B-August-5-L2,MI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0001_i7---UDP0001_i5_18S-B-August-5-L2_R1.gz,MI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0001_i7---UDP0001_i5_18S-B-August-5-L2_R2.gz,UDP0001_i7,GAACTGAGCG,UDP0001_i5,TCGTGGAGCG,A01,1,TCGTCGGCAGCGTCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAG,GTCTCGTGGGCTCGGAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAG,18S
```

Here is my script:

Step 1 : I select the 2nd column of the metadata.csv file, which is the column storing all the name (1 name i.e. 1 file/line)
Step 2: I open each file

```
COLNUM_FILE1=$( cat Desktop/output/fastqs_demultiplexed_for_DADA2/metadata.csv | cut -d ',' -f2)
"${COLNUM_FILE1}"
zsh: command too long: file1\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0001_i7---UDP0001_i5_18S-B-August-5-L2_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0002_i7---UDP0002_i5_18S-B-August-6-L1_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0003_i7---UDP0003_i5_18S-B-August-6-L2_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0004_i7---UDP0004_i5_18S-B-August-6-L3_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0005_i7---UDP0005_i5_COI-A-June-4-L2_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0006_i7---UDP0006_i5_COI-A-June-4-L3_R1.gz\nMI_M06648_0305_001_UDP0009_i7---UDP0009_i5_COI-B-June-4-L2_R1.gz

FILE1=($(awk -F',' -v COLNUM=$COLNUM_FILE1 \
  'NR>1 {print $COLNUM }' "Desktop/output/fastqs_demultiplexed_for_DADA2/metadata.csv" \
  sort | uniq))
```

I get this syntax error (due of the dot I think).

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is 
         >>> MI_M0667292_927_UPD922_i7-----UDP928_i5_18S-August-5-L2_R1. <<<< gz
awk: bailing out at source line 1
awk: syntax error at source line 1
```

Do you have a solution?
rq: I am on MAC OS M1 Monterey 12.6

Comment: What are you expecting `COLNUM_FILE1` to be? It is a single variable, whose value is _all_ second fields of your csv. Instead, you seem to think it is just a single number? What exactly is your awk command trying to do? Why are you executing `"${COLNUM_FILE1}"`? (second line of your script, just above the zsh error). I am afraid most of the commands here don't make sense. For us to help you we need to understand what you are trying to do but since your commands don't really make sense, they aren't helping us understand. Can you please [edit] your question and tell us what you want to do?

Comment: @terdon Actually, it's worse: `COLUMN_FILE1` contains the newline-concatenated content of all values in column 2 of the `.csv` file, including the header. I assume even in `zsh` this cannot be used to populate an array. Then, in the line starting `FILE1`, OP tries to use the entire newline-concatenated list as the number of the column to print (possibly in an attempt to iterate over it, considering the result is again used to populate an array variable).